# SQL query with multiple time based criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database for managing blood lead levels where we have various reporting/exclusion requirements.
For mandatory removal of someone from my area they need a test over 34, and before they are allowed to return they require 3 consecutive tests to be under 27.  I have been using the query below to find people that should be removed this looks at their last 3 tests for any over 34, This works to say a person must be excluded based on their last 3 tests, but does not work to generate a complete list of people that should currently be excluded

```
SELECT x1.[Employee ID]
FROM [Lead Results] AS x1 INNER JOIN Employees ON x1.[Employee ID] = Employees.[Employee ID]
WHERE (((x1.[Test Result])>34) AND (((select count(*)
        from [Lead Results] x2
        where x2.[Employee ID] = x1.[Employee ID]
        and x2.[Date of Test] >= x1.[Date of Test]
    ))<=3))
GROUP BY x1.[Employee ID]
HAVING ((Count(x1.[Date of Test]))>=1);
```

I have also made a query to find people that have their last 3 tests under 27,  This works fine to say someone can now be returned,

```
SELECT x1.[Employee ID]
FROM [Lead Results] AS x1 INNER JOIN Employees ON x1.[Employee ID] = Employees.[Employee ID]
WHERE (((x1.[Test Result])<27) AND (((select count(*)
        from [Lead Results] x2
        where x2.[Employee ID] = x1.[Employee ID]
    and x2.[Date of Test] >= x1.[Date of Test]
    ))<=3))
GROUP BY x1.[Employee ID], Employees.[Current Employee]
HAVING ((Count(x1.[Date of Test]))>=3);
```

obviously these two queries work but only for the last 3 tests.

How can I get all the employee ids for people that have tested over 34, but have not yet had 3 consecutive tests under 27 since their high result.

Comment: Do you have an `AutoNumber` column in the table `[Lead Results]`?

Comment: `[Lead Results]` does have an `AutoNumber` column called `ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the most recent date where you have a test of 34:

```
select [Employee ID], max([Date of Test]) as max34
from [Lead Results]
where [Test Result] > 34
group by [Employee ID];
```

Next, calculate the most recent date where there are three tests all below 27.  This is a bit harder, but it can be done.

The following actually finds tests where the previous, next, and current are all less than 27.  It then aggregates these to get the latest value.

```
select [Employee ID], max([Date of Test]) as MiddleTest27
from [Lead Results] as lr
where [Test Result] < 27 and
      (select top 1 [Test Result]
       from [Lead Results] as lr2
       where lr2.[Employee ID] = lr.[Employee ID] and lr2.[Date of Test] < lr.[Date of Test]
       order by [Date of Test] desc, id desc
      ) < 27 and
      (select top 1 [Test Result]
       from [Lead Results] as lr2
       where lr2.[Employee ID] = lr.[Employee ID] and lr2.[Date of Test] > lr.[Date of Test]
       order by [Date of Test] asc, id asc
      ) < 27
group by [Employee ID]
```

Next, we can combine these to get what you want:  Employees whose most recent test is in the first query but not the second:

```
select e34.*
from (select [Employee ID], max([Date of Test]) as max34
      from [Lead Results]
      where [Test Result] > 34
      group by [Employee ID]
     ) as e34 left join
     (select [Employee ID], max([Date of Test]) as MiddleTest27
      from [Lead Results] as lr
      where [Test Result] < 27 and
            (select top 1 [Test Result]
             from [Lead Results] as lr2
             where lr2.[Employee ID] = lr.[Employee ID] and lr2.[Date of Test] < lr.[Date of Test]
             order by [Date of Test] desc, id desc
            ) < 27 and
            (select top 1 [Test Result]
             from [Lead Results] as lr2
             where lr2.[Employee ID] = lr.[Employee ID] and lr2.[Date of Test] > lr.[Date of Test]
             order by [Date of Test] asc, id asc
            ) < 27
      group by [Employee ID]
     ) as e27
     on e34.[Employee ID] = e27.[Employee ID]
where e27.[Employee ID] is NULL or e27.MiddleTest27 < e34.max34
```

That is, there is either no more recent "27" sequence or the last one predated the "34" sequence.

Comment: Thanks, I am still working through this.  What does "At most one record can be returned by this subquery." mean/signify? I am getting this when trying to run the second query

Comment: @tarriel . . . That is a subquery error, probably caused by the missing `< 27` on the second correlated subquery in the `where` clause.

Comment: I thought that also and put the 27 in to no avail,I tried just the first sub query and it works, then tried just the query with only the first sub query and get the same error.

Comment: @tarriel . . . That signifies that a subquery used in a scalar context is returning more than one row.  The two subqueries used in that context are the ones in the `where` clause.  Each of these has a `top 1`, so they cannot be returning more than one row, except in Access.  This suggests an issue that multiple tests are on the same date.  It can be fixed by including the id.

Comment: Thanks, I would never have gotten there without your help

Comment: I noticed that you or someone accepted my edit but the changes don't appear.  With the code as it is I get the error "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Employee ID' as part of an aggregate function."  If I add `group by [Employee ID]` to the end of the max34 clause it works.  Is this another access quirk?  The answer as written does not quite work for me.

Comment: @tarriel . . . For whatever reason, the edit was rejected (but is available in the history).  I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks!  You have been really helpful.  I can't thank you enough.